# concat a column fields of a table group by the fields of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have two tables say t1 and t2 which join with testid.I need to concat val column of t2 if d1,d2 and id of table t1 is same.Please refer to the following tables.

```
    CREATE TABLE #t1 (d1 varchar(100),d2 varchar(100),id int,testid int)

    INSERT INTO #t1 (d1,d2,id,testid) VALUES ('p','q',1,101)
    INSERT INTO #t1 (d1,d2,id,testid) VALUES ('r','s',2,102)
    INSERT INTO #t1 (d1,d2,id,testid) VALUES ('p','q',1,103)
    INSERT INTO #t1 (d1,d2,id,testid) VALUES ('r','s',1,104)

    CREATE TABLE #t2 (testid int,val varchar(100))

    INSERT INTO #t2 (testid,val) values (101,'x')
    INSERT INTO #t2 (testid,val) values (102,'y')
    INSERT INTO #t2 (testid,val) values (103,'z')
    INSERT INTO #t2 (testid,val) values (104,'xx')

The result should be:

    d1 d2 pid val
    p  q  1   x,z
    r  s  2   y
    r  s  1   xx
```

Comment: What part is causing you difficulty?

Comment: Google:  "sql server aggregate string concatenation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#t1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #t1

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#t2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #t2

CREATE TABLE #t1 (d1 VARCHAR(100), d2 VARCHAR(100), id INT, testid INT)
INSERT INTO #t1 (d1, d2, id, testid)
VALUES ('p', 'q', 1, 101)
     , ('r', 's', 2, 102)
     , ('p', 'q', 1, 103)
     , ('r', 's', 1, 104)

CREATE TABLE #t2 (testid INT, val VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #t2 (testid, val)
VALUES (101, 'x')
     , (102, 'y')
     , (101, 'z')
     , (104, 'xx')

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT d1, d2, id, value = STUFF((
        SELECT [text()] = ',' + val
        FROM #t2
        WHERE #t2.testid = #t1.testid
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')      
    FROM #t1
) t
WHERE t.value IS NOT NULL
```

output -

```
d1  d2  id   value
--- --- ---- ----------------
p   q   1    x,z
r   s   2    y
r   s   1    xx
```

Comment: Thanks.Actually I have others columns eg  a1 in t1 - which also need to be selected. Is it possible with this same query?

Comment: Please provide data sample and expected result.

Comment: Actually, my t1 table is outcome of queries with multiple joins.It has many other fields as well. For simplicity I did not write in my question. e.g.
CREATE TABLE #t1 (a1 varchar(100) d1 VARCHAR(100), d2 VARCHAR(100), id INT, testid INT)

Comment: `SELECT *, value = STUFF(...` ?

Comment: INSERT INTO #t1 (a1,d1, d2, id, testid)
   VALUES ('c','p', 'q', 1, 101)
     , ('d','r', 's', 2, 102)
     , ('c','p', 'q', 1, 103)
     , ('e','r', 's', 1, 104)
and the result:
a1 d1  d2  id   value
--- --- ---- ----------------
c   p   q   1    x,z
d    r   s   2    y
e   r   s   1    xx

Comment: Sorry @Devart the script is not indented as I could not edit question.